# Show/Hide Particular Div on hover and Hide a div on mouse out

Tags: jquery

I had to perform the operation of hide and show a div on clicking a button on a sibling.

But, the operation is happening in other divs too. You can see it in the link below.

Here is the fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/NKC2j/1767/ ).

Script I used,

```
    $(".panel").hide();
    $(".two").hide();

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".slidedown").click(function(){
        $(".panel").slideDown("slow");
        $(".one").hide();
        $(".two").show();
      });
      $(".slideup").click(function(){
        $(".panel").slideUp("slow");
        $(".two").hide();
        $(".one").show();
      });
    });
```

The output I need is,

1. The operation must be for separate box and not all boxes at a time.
   (i,e., the orange box is shown in all black boxes when clicked on the add button instead of just one box.)
2. When the mouse leaves the black box, the class (one) is hiding while (middle-text) is shown. But, after clicking on add and cancel and mouse out, the class (one) is not hiding.

Comment: First find the enclosing product for the current button,

     var $container = $tab.closest('.sep-prod');

Then do operations on elements under it 

     var $contents = $container.find('[data-content]');

This could help you.

Comment: Can you please make it work in the fiddle I made ?

Comment: I have updated your fiddle. Please check. If the fiddle doesn't reflect properly, let me know.

Comment: If http://jsfiddle.net/NKC2j/1768/ is your link, not at all working , Bro !

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NKC2j/1778/

Comment: Bro, http://jsfiddle.net/NKC2j/1779/ is working. But, after we click on the add and cancel and take the mouse out, the links (similar, compare, add) are still there. The links must be hidden and the text alone should be visible whenever we mouse out of that black box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a working fiddle for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/NKC2j/1780/

```
$(".sep-prod").each(function(){
    $(".one,.two,.panel").hide();
        $(this).hover(function(){
            $(this).find(".middle-desc").hide();
            $(this).find(".one").show();
        },function(){
            $(this).find(".one,.two,.panel").hide();
            $(this).find(".middle-desc").show();
    });  
});

$(".slidedown").click(function(){
      $(this).parents().eq(1).find(".one").hide();
      $(this).parents().eq(1).find(".two").show();
      $(this).parents().eq(1).children(".panel").slideDown("slow");
});
```

By using the jquery each function you can apply the hide/show only to the current hovered element.
In the click function you traverse up the dom by two parents with `$(this).parents().eq(1)` and then find the children of that parent that have the class ".panel".

`$(this).parents().eq(1).find(".one").hide();`

If you want the .panel to slideUp after hover out, then this is possible:
http://jsfiddle.net/NKC2j/1781/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NKC2j/1782/ You just missed the hiding part.

But, this is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to identify the container for a given product. Something like this.

```
  $(".slidedown").click(function(event){
      var $productContainer = $(event.target).closest('.sep-prod'); 
    $productContainer.find(".panel").slideDown("slow");
    $productContainer.find(".one").hide();
    $productContainer.find(".two").show();
  });
  $(".slideup").click(function(){
      var $productContainer = $(event.target).closest('.sep-prod'); 
    $productContainer.find(".panel").slideUp("slow");
    $productContainer.find(".two").hide();
    $productContainer.find(".one").show();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, Bro !

jsfiddle.net/NKC2j/1782 is the solution I needed.